# Akka (2.3.0) fails to load Slf4jEventHandler class with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: scala, logging, akka

I migrated from Akka 2.2.3 to 2.3.0-RC4 and got this error message on application startup:

```
error while starting up loggers
akka.ConfigurationException: Logger specified in config can't be loaded 
[akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler] due to
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler]
```

I have these SBT dependencies:

```
val akkaVersion = "2.3.0-RC4"
"com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.10" % akkaVersion
"com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-remote_2.10" % akkaVersion
"com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-kernel_2.10" % akkaVersion
"com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-slf4j_2.10" % akkaVersion
"com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-testkit_2.10" % akkaVersion % "test"
```

Logging worked fine when I was using Akka version 2.2.3 just before I upgraded (no other changes were done in the project).

Here is how I use logger in my `application.conf`:

```
akka.loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]
```

I've checked the jar files downloaded by SBT and `Slf4jEventHandler` is present only in older version:

- Contains NO `Slf4jEventHandler`: `~/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-slf4j_2.10/jars/akka-slf4j_2.10-2.3.0-RC4.jar`
- Contains `Slf4jEventHandler`: `~/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-slf4j_2.10/jars/akka-slf4j_2.10-2.2.3.jar`

I wonder if I should use some other logger class, am I missing dependency, or maybe it's not packaged by mistake. I could not find anything in the docs regarding this change.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I almost opened a ticket because I could not find anything in documentation [here](http://akka.io/news/2014/02/19/akka-2.3.0-RC4-released.html) or [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/logging.html). But then I found this [ticket](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/akka/tickets/3012-remove-deprecated-event-handlers#/activity/ticket%3a) according to which `Slf4jEventHandler` is removed because it was deprecated. I followed up this search and found [scaladoc](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.2.1/index.html#akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler) which has this deprecation message: "(Since version 2.2) use akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger)".

I updated this line in `application.conf`:

```
akka.loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]
```

to this:

```
akka.loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
```

and it all worked.

I hope you find this solution useful.