# What's wrong with my logback.xml with Akka?

Tags: scala, akka, slf4j, logback

Why is my logback logging choking with Akka?  If I leave Akka config alone but delete my logback.xml file it works w/o problems with whatever the defaults are.  Is there a config error in my logback.xml file?

logback.xml

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

application.conf

```
akka {
    loglevel = "ERROR"
    stdout-loglevel = "ERROR"
    loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
    actor {
        provider = akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider
    }
    remote {
        enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
    }
}
```

Build.scala (clip):

```
lazy val root = project.in(file("."))
    .settings(basicSettings: _*)
    .settings(libraryDependencies ++=
        dep_compile(
            typesafe_config, logback, akka_actor, akka_remote, akka_slf4j) ++ 
        dep_test(scalatest)
    )
```

When something attempts to log an error I get:

```
error while starting up loggers
akka.ConfigurationException: Logger specified in config can't be loaded [akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger] due to [akka.event.Logging$LoggerInitializationException: Logger log1-Slf4jLogger did not respond with LoggerInitialized, sent instead [TIMEOUT]]
    at akka.event.LoggingBus$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(Logging.scala:116)
    at akka.event.LoggingBus$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(Logging.scala:115)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
    at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:185)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
...
Caused by: akka.event.Logging$LoggerInitializationException: Logger log1-Slf4jLogger did not respond with LoggerInitialized, sent instead [TIMEOUT]
    at akka.event.LoggingBus$class.akka$event$LoggingBus$$addLogger(Logging.scala:185)
    at akka.event.LoggingBus$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Logging.scala:114)
    at akka.event.LoggingBus$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Logging.scala:113)
    at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:206)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:206)
    at akka.event.LoggingBus$$anonfun$4.apply(Logging.scala:113)
    ... 36 more
```

Comment: What version of Akka?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the old logger class in config. Here is how to fix it:

[Akka (2.3.0) fails to load Slf4jEventHandler class with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943353/akka-2-3-0-fails-to-load-slf4jeventhandler-class-with-java-lang-classnotfounde)

Comment: i'm seeing the same issue, and the accepted answer does not solve the problem. note in the question, `akka.loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]` is already being used.